# TypeError: DiGraph.add_edge() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, graph

When I try to add edges and data to the directed graph it shows this error:

```
TypeError: DiGraph.add_edge() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Here is my code:

```py
HeaderLst=[]
for cell in inSheet[1]:
    if cell.value is not None:
        HeaderLst.append(cell.value)
    else:
        break
AttrList = HeaderLst

lnkDict = collections.OrderedDict()
for row in inSheet.iter_rows():
    attr = 0
    for cell in row[:len(HeaderLst)]:
        lnkDict[HeaderLst[attr]] = cell.value
        attr += 1

Graph = nx.DiGraph()
Graph.add_edge(int(lnkDict["Fnode"]),int(lnkDict["Tnode"]),lnkDict)
```

Comment: Can you update your code so that it's runnable, e.g., include the imports?

Comment: Thanks, Got the answer, I've used Graph.add_edges_from([(int(lnkDict["Fnode"]),int(lnkDict["Tnode"]),lnkDict)]) and it worked for me